# Как найти причину остановки службы Windows?

Tags: c#, windows-service

Есть написанная служба. Как найти причину остановки службы Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обязательно обрабатывайте исключения.
Вариант, который я вижу:

1. Администрирование/ Просмотр событий/Журналы Windows/Приложение
   Вот здесь и ищите причину исключения при работе вашего сервиса
2. Как вариант, перенесите код в обычное приложение (WinForms), хорошо проверьте ваш код и только тогда переносите в службу

Comment: Для простоты отлаживать лучше в консоли.